# Third party .exe program does nothing when instructed to run, program works on other computers

Tags: troubleshooting

Good morning, I have a laptop which cannot run a certain program. This program is used for modeling heavy machinery. Basically, clicking the icon, or trying to run it in other ways, does nothing. It doesn't show in task manager, it doesn't give an error message, it just doesn't run. I've tried running it as administrator, opening in compatibility modes, reinstalling, restarting computer, and nothing occurs. I downloaded the program on another computer and it works just fine.

Anyone have any other suggestions? It's a pretty niche program so there's no real forums of users, and the company said they've never heard of the issue before. Thanks.

Event viewer gave two errors:

.NET Runtime Error:

```
Application: IMPULSELink5.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.Printing.PrintQueueException at MS.Internal.Printing.Configuration.PTProvider.GetPrintCapabilities(System.IO.MemoryStream) at System.Printing.PrintTicketManager.GetPrintCapabilitiesAsXml(System.Printing.PrintTicket) at System.Printing.PrintTicketManager.GetPrintCapabilities(System.Printing.PrintTicket) at System.Printing.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities() at Magnetek.MH.IL5.Views.Printing.Printer.get_PrintCapabilities() at Magnetek.MH.IL5.Views.Printing.PrinterViewModel.get_CollationOptions() at Magnetek.MH.IL5.Views.Printing.PrinterViewModel..ctor(Magnetek.MH.IL5.Views.Printing.Printer) at Magnetek.MH.IL5.Views.Printing.PrintControlViewModel..ctor() Exception Info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings, System.Uri) at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel, System.Uri) at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext, System.Object, Boolean) at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Object, System.Uri) at Magnetek.MH.IL5.Views.MainWindow.InitializeComponent() at Magnetek.MH.IL5.Views.MainWindow..ctor(Magnetek.MH.IL5.Services.Internal.LicensingService, Magnetek.MH.IL5.ViewModels.Services.IMessageBoxService) at Magnetek.MH.IL5.Views.IMPULSELink5Application.Main()
```

Application error:

```
- System 
  - Provider 
   [ Name]  Application Error 
  - EventID 1000 
   [ Qualifiers]  0 

   Level 2 
   Task 100 

   Keywords 0x80000000000000 

  - TimeCreated 
   [ SystemTime]  2018-12-18T18:14:07.748902900Z 
   EventRecordID 1645 
   Channel Application 
   Computer DriveTesting.servername.local 
   Security 

- EventData 

   IMPULSELink5.exe 
   1.0.6255.21046 
   58a492cd 
   KERNELBASE.dll 
   10.0.17134.441 
   3da51fd0 
   e0434352 
   00111812 
   105c 
   01d496fd76eb0caf 
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Magnetek\IMPULSE Link 5\IMPULSELink5.exe 
   C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll 
   2bf61411-edc3-4102-9925-9414adf5c23e
```

Comment: Did you check Event Viewer for error messages yet? Sometimes, SxS errors are not displayed to the user.

Comment: Hard to answer ... operating system, missing Packages, resources, DLL's, rights .......

Comment: @DanielB So I do see a message, but I'm a bit out of my league in terms of figuring out what it means: Application: IMPULSELink5.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Application: IMPULSELink5.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.Printing.PrintQueueException at MS.Internal.Printing.Configuration.PTProvider.GetPrintCapabilities(System.IO.MemoryStream) at System.Printing.PrintTicketManager.GetPrintCapabilitiesAsXml(System.Printing.PrintT

Comment: @bummi It works on another computer with the same operating system, and I redownloaded it on both computers for fresh installs, so I'd think nothing could be missing. Every other program I've tried to use is working fine.

Comment: Change your default printer and try again. Then please [edit] your post and include the entirety of the error message you referenced in your comment above.

Comment: @Appleoddity I went ahead and changed the default printer and updated my post. The error messages posted are from after changing the printer.

Comment: I see printer references and a licensing reference? Does this product use a parallel port keyfob for licensing? Does it control or work with a “printer” device? I would try removing any installed printers for now and just doing some cleanup work around that.

Comment: @Appleoddity Doesn't seem to need a keyfob, as I can open it just fine on my other computer once I've downloaded it. I personally don't use the software (I'm helping a coworker), but it looks to allow the user to look at .ds4, .ts4, .par, and .parx files, and then print them.

Comment: Well it appears to be having trouble enumerating features of one of your installed printers.

Comment: In case anyone is interested: The software is available for download [here](https://www.magnetekmh.com/Material%20Handling/Downloads) (IMPULSE Link 5 Viewer).

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is an internal error in the program. From the stack trace, we can deduct that it tries to get available collation options from a printer. Some printer drivers have problems with this operation as performed by the .NET Framework library.

The program needs to handle that error. There is nothing you can do except contact the vendor, preferably with the event log error you have. It’s enough for them to identify and work around the issue.

In the meantime, you could try uninstalling printers until the program no longer crashes. Start with real printers and remove virtual printers (like the PDF Printer) only after that.